# Colocar un JPanel sobre otro JPanel en Java Swing - Error

Tags: java, jframe, design, jpanel

Tengo un `formulario` de este tipo con los datos de un cliente, el cliente lo extraigo del `combobox`.

**Se carga en el `combobox` todos lo `DNIs` de la base de datos**, y eligiendo el deseado, se completan los datos de la interfaz asignando a cada campo su valor correspondiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Inicialmente, al ejecutar el programa, sale el `combobox` desplegable para elegir los `DNIs`. Quiero que mientas esté sin elegir un `DNI` (al principio de la ejecución), me sale un `gif`/`label` poniendo "Cargando..."-"Eligiendo DNI...".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PROBLEMA:**

Los `jLabels` y `jTextFields` están dentro de `JPanel_Cliente`, el cual está desactivado mientras no se cargue un `DNI`. El problema lo tengo porque quiero poner otro `JPanel` para el "Cargando..." en mitad del `JFrame` pero como está ocupado el "espacio" por el `JPanel_Cliente` entonces se me descoloca toda la app. Es decir, un `JPanel` no puede ocupar el espacio de otro.

**Código:**

```
private void jComboBox_DNIsItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                
        String dni = (String) jComboBox_DNIs.getSelectedItem();
        //Si el index del jComboBox_DNIs es distinto de cero, existe DNI y entonces...
        if(jComboBox_DNIs.getSelectedIndex()!=0) {
            button_OK.setVisible(true);
            button_limpiar.setVisible(true);
            JPanel_Cliente.setVisible(true);
            Object[] datos_dni = Conexiones.datos_de_un_dni(dni);
            textfield_nombre.setText(String.valueOf(datos_dni[0]));
            textfield_nombre.setEditable(false);
            //... el resto ...
            button_OK.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            button_OK.setVisible(false);
            button_limpiar.setVisible(false);
            JPanel_Cliente.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

**¿Qué solución puedo tener? ¿Hay solución?**

Comment: Puedes colocar ambos en el mismo lugar jugando con el `setVisible` poniendo uno en `true` y el otro en `false` pero su funcionamiento depende de como estés "armando" la interfaz gráfica. Para que funcione yo usaría un `BoxLayout` de una columna y 3 filas siendo la del medio para los `JPanel` en cuestión. La fila de arriba que contenga el label y el combo box, y la de abajo que contenga los botones. Luego en cada fila del `BoxLayout` usa otros layouts para que los componentes te queden bien acomodados.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que debas generar dos JPanel. En el mismo ocultas o mostras, segun el caso, los elementos necesarios. Para el gif, activas el label y desctivas el resto. Con setVisible(true o false). Deberias aclarar que layout usas. Suerte

Comment: Y si quiero ocupar todo el JPanel que ya tengo creado para cambiar el formulario por el gif de Cargando... No creo que sea buena solución. Me explico: ahora cambiar el setVisible a 5-6-7-8 elementos es sencillo, ¿pero y si son 50?

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución puede ser poner un tercer panel de capas en juego, este panel es quien contendrá los otros dos panales, el del gif y el del formulario:

`JLayeredPane PanelBase = new JLayeredPane();`

Este panel en capas le permitirá especificar que algunos componentes secundarios deben superponerse sobre otros componentes secundarios.

```
JPanel PanelFormulario = new JPanel();
JPanel PanelGif = new JPanel();

PanelBase.add(PanelFormulario, 2, 0); 
PanelBase.add(PanelGif, 1, 0);
```

Una vez su panel contenedor del gif este sobre el panel con el formulario, si podrá usar la propiedad `.setVisible(true/false)`

Agrego un ejemplo donde pondremos 3 Jpanel en la misma posición, utilizamos el LayeredPane el cual tendrá la mismas dimensiones del Jframe y un fondo de color gris oscuro, los 3 Jpanel también tendrán color, en este caso el amarillo estará al fondo, el Rojo en el medio y el azul estará al frente por encima de los otros dos Jpanel:

```
package Superponer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Capas extends JFrame{
    
    public Capas(){
    
        setSize(1200,600);
        setTitle("Super Poner");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
    
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] ARGS){
    
        Capas ventana = new Capas();
        
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        
        JLayeredPane PanelBase = new JLayeredPane();
        
        PanelBase.setLayout(null);
        PanelBase.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        PanelBase.setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 600);
        PanelBase.setOpaque(true);
        
        
        JPanel panelbajo = new JPanel();
        panelbajo.setSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
        panelbajo.setLocation(600 - (500/2), 300 - (100/2));
        panelbajo.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        PanelBase.add(panelbajo, new Integer(1));
        
        JPanel panelMedio = new JPanel();
        panelMedio.setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        panelMedio.setLocation(600 - (400/2), 300 - (100/2));
        panelMedio.setBackground(Color.red);
        PanelBase.add(panelMedio, new Integer(2));
        
        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelTop.setSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        panelTop.setLocation(600 - (300/2), 300 - (100/2));
        panelTop.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        PanelBase.add(panelTop, new Integer(3));
        
        ventana.getContentPane().add(PanelBase);
        
    }
    
}
```